# How to find first sunday of next month in Java 8?

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, dayofweek, localdate

I searched on StackOverflow for the same, but all the answers are for legacy java versions.
I did not find any of the answers with Java 8 Data and Time utility.
Can anybody help me out for the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find out a way using LocalDate and TemporalAdjuster's with() method as follows:

```
LocalDate firstSundayOfNextMonth = LocalDate
              .now()
              .with(firstDayOfNextMonth())
              .with(nextOrSame(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY));
```

Comment: I am confused. The title of your question says: find first SUNDAY, but your answer mentions MONDAY.